# Automapper - How to disable cache when projecting without Mapper.Reset?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, automapper

I have what I think be a very routine scenario using AutoMapper, which is an attempt at mapping a projection dynamically in order not to query the database for columns that I won't be using:

```
var map = Mapper.CreateMap<Source, DestinationViewModel>();
map.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

if (conditionForFieldA)
  map.ForMember(vm => vm.FieldA, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.FieldAbc));
if (conditionForFieldB)
  map.ForMember(vm => vm.FieldB, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.FieldDef));
if (conditionForFieldC)
  map.ForMember(vm => vm.FieldC, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.FieldGhi));
```

What seems to be the problem is that AutoMapper will cache mapping settings to Source and DestinationViewModel and won't accept/consider different mappings to the same . This causes the issue that I am facing: it sometimes will have conditionForFieldA met, and sometimes won't; regardless this simple logic, it will only query the database for the same columns that were projected after the first Mapper.CreateMap got called.

Since it's an ASP.NET Web API project, Mapper.Reset() doesn't seem to be a good choice since AutoMapper setup happens only once (Application_Start()), but it would be fantastic if I could reset just that very specific  mappings setup only.

Has anyone come across with a scenario like this and was able to solve it using AutoMapper before?

Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for the same functionality. My current work around is to pull all the data back. Hopefully Automapper has a solution for this.